# Distance from a point toward another point

Tags: math, geometry

Given point a point a (x1,y1) and a point c (x3,y3) we can calculate a slope m. Assuming we have a distance d I'm a bit stuck trying to figure out how to find a point b (x2,y2) which is d distance from x1,y1 in the direction of c.

Does anyone know how to calculate this? I thought about using the midpoint function but it's not quite there.

Help?

Comment: Not programming-related. You might have better luck on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Cody, I've found that the math bods are rather elitist. They're likely to laugh at a question this basic, instead preferring ones that the vast majority of mortal can't even read, let alone understand, like `structure constant and Clebsch-Gordan coefficients` :-) Since this is a common programming problem in terms of graphics and/or games, I think it's probably okay here. It is asking for an algorithm after all.

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo - it is for a game, so I think it is a common programming issue.

Comment: @pax: Fair point that there is some overlap. Although it was my understanding that math.se was designed for "mere mortals", and it was the Math Overflow people who were the elitists. It would be a shame that *both* sites turned out that way. There needs to be a place for asking this type of question.

Comment: @Cody, I may be mistaken. Perhaps it _was_ MO, rather than M.SE, where I had the trouble. I apologise to the M.SE bods if that's the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work out the *full* distance between `a` and `c` with:

```
        __________________________________
df =   / (x3-x1)*(x3-x1) + (y3-y1)*(y3-y1)
     \/
```

This uses the standard "root of the sum of squares" method.

Then, if the actual *partial* distance you want is `dp`, the point can be found at (x2,y2) with:

```
x2 = x1 + dp/df * (x3-x1)
y2 = y1 + dp/df * (y3-y1)
```

which is simply moving the correct proportion `dp/df` in both dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the direction from A to B by the following:

```
D = B - A
```

Then, you may normalize the direction (which means it is magnitude 1, or length 1):

```
N = D / D.Length
```

where

```
D.Length = sqrt(D.X * D.X + D.Y * D.Y)
```

To find a point on the line given by A and B, X units away from A in the direction of B, you would use the following:

```
Final = A + N * X
```